# WSO2 APIM 4.0 : The requested resource is not available

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

I have a **published working API** on the API manager and I made some changes in the API code in the integration studio then exported a CAR file.

After that I have deployed the car file of my API in the **micro integrator 7.1.0** and restarted the micro integrator then make save and deploy in the API manager to publish a new version of the API (usually this works with no issues, and I have done this several times)

The API Endpoint configuration is load balanced on two service urls as follows:

http://10.10.10.1:8290/demo-api/

http://10.10.10.2:8290/demo-api/

when invoking curl in the **backend server (micro integrator)** it works just fine and return result:

```
curl -X GET http://10.10.10.1:8290/demo-api/getCountriesLookup
```

but when calling the API through the **API manager** as follows:

`curl -X GET https://am.mydomain:443/demo/1.0.0/getCountriesLookup`

I get the following response :

```
{
    "code": "404",
    "type": "Status report",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "description": "The requested resource is not available."
}
```

When viewing the API manager logs I see the following exception :

```
TID: [-1] [] [2022-12-14 10:53:40,921]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-14 10:53:41,129]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /demo/1.0.0/getCountriesLookup, HEALTH CHECK URL = /demo/1.0.0/getCountriesLookup
TID: [-1] [] [2022-12-14 10:53:42,270] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - HttpException occurred org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid request line: GET /
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:209)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection$LoggingNHttpMessageParser.parse(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:410)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection$LoggingNHttpMessageParser.parse(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:384)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpServerConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpServerConnection.java:262)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection.consumeInput(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onInputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onInputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:39)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ParseException: Invalid request line: GET /
        at org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser.parseRequestLine(BasicLineParser.java:302)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpRequestParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpRequestParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:50)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeadLine(AbstractMessageParser.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:207)
        ... 14 more
```

NOTE : the API Manager logs mentioned RESOURCE = `/demo/1.0.0/getCountriesLookup`
instead of `RESOURCE = /demo-api/1.0.0/getCountriesLookup`
I don't know why ? where did this context comes from ?

**UPDATE** : added API endpoint configuration screenshot

[image]

[image]

**Update 2** : The URL I get in the try out console in the API Manager

```
curl -X 'GET' \'https://am.mydomain:443/demo/1.0.0/getCountriesLookup' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
```

Comment: What is the url you get in the try out console in the API Manager?

Comment: `curl -X 'GET' \' https://am.mydomain:443/demo/1.0.0/getCountriesLookup' \
      -H 'accept: */*' \`

Comment: When you expose the services from the API Manager, you have to use this url to access the API. You can't use the demo-api which is the backend url.

Comment: Does this url work?

Comment: When accessing the API I use the API manager url : 'https://am.mydomain/demo/1.0.0/getCountriesLookup' and it produces  `The requested resource is not available`

Comment: @Pubci
,Thanks a lot for your time and support, I resolved the issue by deleting the api from the API manager and creating it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by deleting the API from the API manager and creating it again.

Answer (score 1):

With APIM 4.0.0, in order for a change to be applied in the gateway, you need to create a new revision and deploy that revision in the gateway. The lifecycle state and the deployment states are now decoupled compared to precision versions.

Can you verify whether your latest changes are revisioned and deployed properly in the gateway?

Comment: yes I created a new revision.
I edited the question and added more details.

Comment: Can you use the gateway REST API[1] and verify that the resource is deployed properly? You can check for the api-artifact as well as the endpoint to verify that the correct endpoint configurations are deployed in the gateway.   

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/gateway-apis/gateway-v2/gateway-v2/

Comment: Which API I should use to verify ?

Comment: https://apis.wso2.com/api/am/gateway/v2/api-artifact and https://apis.wso2.com/api/am/gateway/v2/end-points

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for your time and support, I resolved the issue by deleting the api from the API manager and creating it again.